# Why does Ionic CLI make module files?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

When using latest Ionic CLI, its making module files. Why does it make a module file? Also, how do I properly register this module? What is the benefit of having a tab or page generated with a module file vs without? For example, when installing tabs default project(`ionic start myApp tabs`) you don't get tabs with module files, and with the generator you do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of the module files is lazy loading. You don't need to register it. It is a self-contained module file for the particular page.But if you don't need lazy loading then you can use this CLI for generating pages.

```
ionic generate page MyPage --no-module
```

***Note:*** I highly suggest you to use `Lazy loading`. It'll give huge performance boost to your app.

Here you can read more about [**lazy loading**](https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/).

Comment: excellent resource included, thank you! just the kind of explanation i was looking for.